# Hide youtube link and video source

Tags: javascript, php, youtube

I want to hide the source of my youtube video embedded on the website
I have googled a lot and I have found that this feature is deleted .
DO anyone know any clean method to do this.

```
<iframe title="Tip1" width="1218" height="914" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx?feature=oembed"
        frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen="" data-gtm-yt-inspected-1_19="true"></iframe>
```

Trying to show youtube link without the user can know about the vide source
NB: The most important question is if that possible or not possible on Wordpress Site

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please provide your code

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't. The same way if you shorten a url into something else then visit it; it will show the original link

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the video(s) server-side, and either store them to stream them to the client, or directly streaming from youtube to the client.
It will be way harder that just adding the youtube iframe, because you'll need to learn how to get video from YT, then how to stream video file to a website, etc..
Also please read the YouTube Terms of Services before doing anything so you'll know if you can or not make what you wants (legally speaking), because i'm not aware about how you can legally stream from YT.